# Read XSD file in Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, schema

I have a workflow webservice with multiple activities exposed as servicemethods. Those servicemethods have various parameters. In Java, I need to know what those parameters are.

So I figured there is a XSD schema from which I should be able to get the information i`d like to know. Is there a way to read elements from a XSD file within Java? My XSD basically looks like this:

```
<xs:element name='servicemethod'>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence><xs:element name='parameterIWantToKnow'/></xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In Java, I do know the 'servicemethod', but I want to know the element names nested in this servicemethod element.

Or is there something like parsing XML to JSON, because I have done something like this before with JSON in Java.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Michael.

Maybe my question was a little bit confusing. But to be more explicit: I have a worflow, hosted as a service in IIS. All my workflow retrieve-activities are exposed as a webservice operation. But all these operations have parameters, now in Java I want to know what those paramters are. So I thought, by reading the XSD file I would be able to retrieve those names? Because my XSD is just like this:

```
<xs:element name='servicemethod'>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence><xs:element name='parameterIWantToKnow'/></xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>.
```

I do know the servicemethod name in Java, now i want to know the element names nested in this servicemethod element. Btw, my XSD is only available via a URL, not as a file on my pc.

Btw, i`m neiter a Java expert or a XML expert, so sorry to be asking things that probably dont make sense to you..

Comment: Btw, the XSD being only available via URL should be no problem, I just realised a simple get request would be enough to get the content of the document..

Answer (score 0):

It rather depends what you want to do with the data ("consume" it isn't very explicit...). An XML Schema is written as a set of XML documents and to make sense of it you will usually need all the documents in the set. To answer reasonable questions using the information in the schema, such as "can a paragraph element contain another paragraph element?", you will really want to work from the compiled schema (the so-called schema component model) rather than from the raw XML. There's a Xerces API for doing this, called XSOM, or the Saxon-EE product has a tool that generates an XML representation of the schema component model, which can be processed using XPath or XQuery.

Comment: My answer was to long to be a comment, so please see my answer on the post. Thanks